# dotless.compiler Invalid RGB color string

Tags: powershell, less, dotless

Hi i'm using Powershell and dotless.Compiler.exe version 1.3.1.0 to compile my less files.
I'm getting a error trying to compile a less with a variable using a background color.
So I have the value

```
@varBodyBg: #669900 repeat-x left top scroll url(images/img.png);

@varBodyBgString:"@{varBodyBg}";
@varBodyBgColor:color(@varBodyBgString);
```

But I'm getting this error trying to use the function color:

```
Invalid RGB color string '669900 repeat-x left top scroll url(images/img.png)' on line 5 in file 'MainFile.less':
[4]: @varBodyBgString:"@{varBodyBg}";
[5]: @varBodyBgColor:color(@varBodyBgString); 
     ----------------^
```

Or if the

```
@varBodyBg: rgb(0,0,0);
```

Give the error

```
Invalid RGB color string 'black' on line 4 in file 'MainFile.less':
[3]: @varBodyBgString:"@{varBodyBg}";
[4]: @varBodyBgColor:color(@varBodyBgString); 
   ----------------^
```

Someone can tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: I know the `color()` function has issues with processing color names (like "black"), but what I cannot figure out is why the code you have is producing 'black' as a value for `@BodyBgString` when it should be the string `#ebe9e7`. I don't actually have your "Powershell and dotless` setup to test, so that part is a mystery to me.

Comment: mysterious indeed =) I wonder what gets actually assigned to `@BodyBg`. Did you already figure anything out Pedro?

Comment: I still don't have any clue what is causing this.

Comment: Updated the first post

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because DotLess compiles colour values to their shortest version.  Hence `black` has a shorter number of characters than `rgb(0,0,0)` but both have the same meaning.  The same would be true of `#FFFFFF`, compiling to `white`.